# Binomial or Poisson

Tags: poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

A telemarketer makes 5 phone calls per hour and is able to make a sale on 40% of all the contacts.

Q1: What is the probability of making exactly 3 sales in 1 hour?

Which distribution, binomial or Poisson, is more suitable? I would go for binomial, but Poisson seems correct as well.

Let X be the number of sales made per hour.

1. Binomial: X~B(n=5, p=0.4)

P(X=3) = 5C3 x (0.4)^3 x (0.6)^2 = 0.2304

Justification: 2 outcomes. Independent Bernoulli experiments.

2. Poisson: In one hour, 5 phone calls were made and 5 x 0.4 = 2 sales per hour.

X~Po(lambda = 2)

P(X=3) = (e^-2)(3^2)/2! = 0.1804

Justification: On average, 2 sales are made per hour.

Q2: What is the probability of making at most 3 sales in two hours?
Answer obtained using binomial: 0.618
Answer obtained using Poisson: 0.433

If both distributions can be used, then I would expect to obtain the same answer.

Comment: Notice that the poisson distribution gives positive probability for $Pr(X\geq 6)$ (*while the binomial gives this a probability of zero*), but we are told the (*in my opinion*) **very explicit** sentence "*A telemarketer* **makes 5 phonecalls per hour**", which is decidedly different than "*A telemarketer makes an average of 5 phonecalls per hour (but possibly a different number than 5)*".  That being said, poisson is the incorrect one to use here and the correct one to use is the binomial distribution.

Comment: Poisson gives you approximate probability, and it's gives good approximation when $p$ is small and $n$ is big.